# string match and remove each row in a postgresql

Tags: postgresql

So in short:

- I need to find all rows in the column `Translation` that begin with the letter **M** (**M123** is one of the Prefixes) and then I need to remove the **M123** and similar prefixes from all the rows.

For example, row 1 contains the following data:
**M123 - This is translated from Spanish to English**

And I need to remove the `M123 -` from the mentioned data. And this I need to do for the `Translation` column in every row in the table.

It's been a while since I actually did some SQL-Queries. So I tried a WHERE clause to find all the M prefixes but my query returns an empty search. Following is the query I am using atm:

```
SELECT Translation from Translation_Table where Translation like 'M';
```

I am a little bit confused right now. So any help is appreciated.

Comment: your question is a bit confusing! you want to find all rows where Translation starts with M and then remove it from Translation, am I right?? how about column Translation is it holding only `M123`  or `M123 something` or `something M123 something`  or in every column??

Comment: Thank you for the input. I will edit the question asap.

Comment: can you share the structure of your table?? and you said `I need to do it for every row in the table` what do you mean by this, changing the Translation column in every row??

Comment: Changing the data in the every row of the Translation column where the prefix M123 or similar is found.

Comment: This does not directly address the question. But an observation you need to realize and keep in mind.  When you use a predicate of the form *string like pattern* where the pattern does not contain a wildcard character (_%) is equivalent to the predicate *string = pattern*. So in this case `where Translation like 'M'` is the same as `where Translation = 'M';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sense that you might be wanting to do an *update* here, rather than a select:

```sql
UPDATE Translation_Table
SET Translation = REGEXP_REPLACE(Translation, 'M[0-9]+', '')
WHERE Translation ~ '^M[0-9]+';
```

Answer (score 0):

addition to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72880958/4235636) following query will remove all occurence of **M[any length of a number]**

```
UPDATE Translation_Table
SET Translation = REGEXP_REPLACE(Translation, '[M[:digit:]]', '', 'g')
WHERE Translation ~ '.M[0-9]*';
```